# Drop down list chosen text duplication

Tags: drop-down-list

In country drop down list example, do I have to repeat the chosen country in a a new title (indicated with a red arrow) or this will be considered as a duplication? what is the best practice in this case?[image]

I have attached the example.

Comment: Hi See,
what do you mean with "repeat"? The dropdown already displays Egypt as the chosen country. I don't know why you would want to have a separate label below with Egypt again.

Comment: HI @See, welcome to the site. A bit more context would be helpful. What is Lorem ispum supposed to be? A description of any kind that is related to the selected value in the dropdown?

Comment: @greenforest, [Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) has been used for over a century by printers as a better version of "*Blatant filler. Blatant filler. Blatant filler. …*".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

Can the user change the dropdown without the text immediately being updated? Will the dropdown control ever move farther away from the text, on any viewport, so that the user no longer sees dropdown and text as one chunk of information? In that case, use a header.

If the dropdown is always going to be visually and functionally attached to the text right below it, you can likely hide the header. It would be considerate for your screen reader users to have a label they can hear, so they don't have to deal with the dropdown for context.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's redundant to put a title to a dropdown menu, especially in cases where the chosen option has an immediate related text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly uncommon to have a separate text display of the selected answer. It could be confusing because it resembles all the other hard-coded text, whereas we know by the appearance of the input areas that it is malleable data.